# Memory committed(commit limit) not reflecting

Tags: iis

I have several virtual IIS servers (2016) with multiple applications.
26 GB RAM
8 vCPU
Im getting lots of Event ID: 2004 in event viewer on several servers:

> Log Name: System
> Source: Microsoft-Windows-Resource-Exhaustion-Detector
> Event ID: 2004
> Task Category: **Resource Exhaustion Diagnosis Events**
> Level: Warning
> Keywords: Events related to exhaustion of system commit limit (virtual memory).
> User: SYSTEM
> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: w3wp.exe (47500) consumed 1342939136 bytes, w3wp.exe (18704) consumed 1042980864 bytes, and w3wp.exe (10612) consumed 1007996928 bytes.

I moved the paging file to a separate 75GB size partition

however I still see the commit limit is ~35GB
[as mentioned by Jamie Hanrahan](https://superuser.com/questions/482678/commit-charge-is-100-full-but-physical-memory-is-just-60-when-using-no-page-fi), commit limit = current pagefile size + RAM size

my questions are:
why is the commit limit not growing to its full potential(26GBRAM+75GB PF)?
why does the w3wp.exe applications not consuming more memory if they need it ?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I think you should concern why w3wp.exe consumed much more memory.  Rather than move the paging file to a separate 75GB size partition.

It may be a problem about IIS [high memory usage](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/High-memory-usage-on-IIS-Worker-Process-w3wp-exe?language=en_US), or your IIS is supposed to consume so much memory.